# Very strange- sculpt mode hides vertices

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, sculpting, weight-painting, vertex-paint

Very weird issue!! Blender 2.90.1

In edit mode my model appears to be as normal, no part of the mesh is hidden (alt + H). If I enter either weight paint mode, vertex paint mode or sculpt mode no changes can be applied to the mesh. I can't sculpt the mesh and I cant weight or vertex paint onto it. If I return back to edit mode, all of the meshes vertices are now hidden, I can bring them back with Alt + H. However the mesh isn't hidden, just the individual vertices...

Example with images:

Edit mode > into sculpt mode > back into edit mode

This is my original mesh in edit mode

[image: Edit mode]

This is the viewport toggled to sculpt mode

[image: Sculpt Mode]

This is the mesh with hidden vertices when back in edit mode. the mesh can be returned to its original state by hitting Alt + H

[image]

I need to be able to sculpt!! Help!

Some details:

The mesh is a character that has an armature applied from mixamo, with weights, however it was previously working so I don't think that is the route of the problem

The Problem applies only to the specific object AND I joined other objects to it (Ctrl + J) and they are able to be sculpted - their vertices don't get hidden when toggling in and out of sculpt mode so it is only specific vertices within that object. This is shown here: (please excuse the terrible topology- I'm not fixing it) [image]

The problem does not resolve by appending the object to a new file.

I will try exposing the object as an obj and re- importing it but that's a quick fix and I would really like to solve this issue.

Thank you for your help I really appreciate any input.

(Computer specs MacbookPro Pro, Processor - 2.8 GHz Intel Core i5, Memory - 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 Graphics - Intel Iris 1536 MB. Don't know if this is helpful but the more info the better)

Comment: please upload your blend file here, https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?ref=be-community-add-2 otherwise we cant know what is happening...

Comment: Hello thank you for your response - the problem seems to occur when unhiding the vertices in edit mode. for the vertices to be usable in sculpt mode they have to be unhidden in sculpt mode... Which seems very odd and fairly unintuitive. hope this helps someone.

Comment: yeah use mask hide option in sculpt mode instead if you want to hide something...